# EXCEL how to use vlookup on financial

Tags: excel

I have question for you. I need use vlookup here. I have two sheet. First where i have empty resukt, The second is where I have a financial plan in input7_pl. How to make function sonthsy with change of datę 2020.8 to 2020.9 for example the function will be update a table im trying =vlookup but i Got #adr

Comment: You must post some sample data and expected output. Also post your current formula which is not giving you correct result.

Comment: =vlookup(0$1,input7_PL!$K1,DN123,2,0) i will try add some picture

Comment: Vlookup has only 4 parameter but you entered 5. Try `=Vlookup(O$1,input7_PL!$K1,2,0)`

Comment: K1:DN123 not K1,DN123. Replace your comma with a colon.